# uncommitted data in one transaction get access by other transaction.. why?

Tags: mysql

insert query or update query  in one transaction get auto committed even I don't commit it under that transaction  and inserted data get access by other transaction? why this is happening.
Ex:

I Tries below two transaction in two different sessions:
session 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
```

session 2:

```
START TRANSACTION;

 select * from test where id=1
```

This gets executed and gives me data of id 1;

Now, I want to ask that, how this possible if I don't commit insert query in first transaction then how data of inserted query get accessed in second transaction.

I read most of the links on stackoverflow but they says that

Everything you did inside the same transaction is visible to later commands inside the same transaction. **Just not to other transactions until committed**. This is true for all isolation levels except Read uncommitted.

my innodb config setting are like:

autocommit   ON

innodb_commit_concurrency    0

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit   1

tx_isolation REPEATABLE-READ

is this setting affect data during transaction:

Comment: You yourself answered your query. Setting is `autocommit ON` so whenever some DML will occur it would be autocommit.

Comment: if I change my setting in conf file and set autocommit to OFF then will it work?

Comment: It should in ideal condition..

Comment: then whats the use of transaction?

Comment: REPEATABLE-READ

Answer (score 0):

You probably use tables of engine type MyISAM. These do not support transactions. Use engine type InnoDB instead. You can simply convert your tables with

```
ALTER TABLE foo ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To check, which engine is used, check the last lines of

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G
```